# Creating multiple LAS datasets from LiDAR files in various directories using model builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, lidar, iterator

I have 60 folders each containing approximately 20 LiDAR files in .las format. I want to create one LAS dataset from .las files from each folder, and each LAS dataset is named by the folder name. I thought it would be straightforward to use iterator in model builder (ArcGIS 10.1) but unfortunately I couldn't find the suitable iterator, as it doesn't seem to iterate by folders. I tried "iterate files" and "iterate multivalue" but, struggle to produce individual LAS dataset by the folder name.

Could anyone give me some ideas or tips to complete my task?

Comment: Do you have access to [FME](http://www.safe.com/)?

Comment: No I don't, would FME do the job? Thanks. @Martin

Comment: I would think so, but have to leave a full answer to someone with more experience in the program.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to skip arcgis for this task and do it directly from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc14/tech-workshops/tw_471.pdf
Running multiple renditions of slide # 5 might be your only option if you have 20 folders and then press play.  I had Bare Earth / First Returns and ARCMAP only ran them one at a time taking 2 hours for over 800 tiles.

A lesson learned if you move the datasets around and see a \ inside the red box for the tiles just recalculate your LAS stats.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Also, I did not understand the connection of slide #5 with the question and your answer. It is also good to cite properly the source you are using (in this case a lecture from an ESRI Workshop of Weitz and Benkelman, 2014)?

Comment: The slide referenced the work flow... The cited source is the link the referencing is up to your publication's format.